# Why can I return a reference to an owned value of a function?

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

In chapter 19.2 of *The Rust Programming Language*, the following example compiles without any error. I found out from [issue #1834](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/1834) that there is a new lifetime elision rule that implicitly makes `'s` longer than `'c`.

Although I couldn't find a detailed explanation of this new elision rule, I guess that it is not more than *just* an implicit version of the longer, more explicit constraint: `<'c, 's: 'c>`.  I think however my confusion is probably not about this new elision rule but of course I could be wrong about this.

My understanding is, that `parse_context` takes ownership of `context` as it has not been borrowed but actually moved to the function.  That alone implies to me that the lifetime of `context` should match the lifetime of the function it is owned by regardless of the lifetimes and constraint we defined in `Context`, and `Parser`.

Based on those definitions, the part where `context` outlives the temporary `Parser` makes perfect sense to me (after all, we defined a longer lifetime), but the part where the `&str` reference is not dropped when `context` goes out of scope at the end of `parse_context` and I can still safely return it -- makes me puzzled.

What have I missed?  How can the compiler reason about the lifetime of the returned `&str`?

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

```rust
struct Context<'s>(&'s str);

struct Parser<'c, 's>
{
    context: &'c Context<'s>,
}

impl<'c, 's> Parser<'c, 's>
{
    fn parse(&self) -> Result<(), &'s str>
    {
        Err(self.context.0)
    }
}

fn parse_context(context: Context) -> Result<(), &str>
{
    Parser { context: &context }.parse()
}

fn main()
{
    let mut s = String::new();
    s += "Avail";
    s += "able?";
    if let Err(text) = parse_context(Context(&s))
    {
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Context<'s>(&'s str);
```

→ Values of type `Context` hold a string with some lifetime `'s`. This lifetime is implicitly at least as long as the lifetime of the context, but it may be longer.

```
struct Parser<'c, 's>
{
    context: &'c Context<'s>,
}
```

→ Values of type `Parser` hold a a reference to context with some lifetime `'c`. This context holds a string with some *other* lifetime `'s`.

```
impl<'c, 's> Parser<'c, 's>
{
    fn parse(&self) -> Result<(), &'s str>
    {
        Err(self.context.0)
    }
}
```

→ Function `parse` returns a value with lifetime `'s`, ie. with *the same lifetime as the string that is stored inside the context,* which is not the same as the lifetime of the context itself.

```
fn parse_context(context: Context) -> Result<(), &str>
{
    Parser { context: &context }.parse()
}
```

→ I'm not sure exactly where this is specified, but obviously the compiler infers that the lifetime for the returned string is the same as the `'s` parameter used for the context. Note that even though the context itself is moved into `parse_context`, this only affects the context itself, not the string that it contains.

```
fn main()
{
    let mut s = String::new();
```

→ Create a new string valid until the end of `main`

```
    s += "Avail";
    s += "able?";
    if let Err(text) = parse_context(Context(&s))
```

→ Create a new context and move it into `parse_context`. It will automatically be dropped at the end of `parse_context`. It holds a reference to string `s` which is valid until the end of `main` and `parse_context` returns a string with the same lifetime as `s` ⇒ `text` is valid until the end of `main`.

```
    {
        println!("{}", text);
    }
}
```

→ No problem: `text` is valid until the end of `main`.

Comment: It is a much more detailed explanation of the same conclusion that I summarised in my answer.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Please always use `rustfmt` to format your code according to the guidelines. You can find it under tools in the upper right corner of [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org)

Answer (score 2):

You are **not** returning a reference to the owned value of the function. You are returning a copy of the reference passed in.

Your function is an elaborate version of the identity function:

```
fn parse_context(s: &str) -> &str {
    s
}
```

In your real code, you take a reference to a struct containing a string slice, then another reference to the string slice, but all of those references are thrown away.

For example, there's an unneeded reference in `parse`:

```
fn parse(&self) -> Result<(), &'s str> {
    Err( self.context.0)
    //  ^ no & needed
}
```

Additionally, if you enable some more lints, you'll be forced to add more lifetimes to your function signature, which might make things more clear:

```
#![deny(rust_2018_idioms)]

fn parse_context(context: Context<'_>) -> Result<(), &'_ str> {
    Parser { context: &context }.parse()
}
```

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423)

> Although I couldn't find a detailed explanation of this new elision rule,

[`T: 'a` inference in structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/inference-in-structs.html) in the edition guide.

Comment: Let me get this straight then: in the identity function the copy of `s` (the type of which is a reference) isn't the copy of the reference itself but also entire object it is referencing (in our case the slice)?

Comment: No, the copy of `s` is indeed the copy of the reference. However in your case it is a reference to the `'static` string `"Available?"` defined in your `main` function that will never be dropped since it's `'static`.

Comment: @Jmb that's exactly what I thought earlier, but as you can see -- I updated the example -- even if I create a `String` on the heap, add some characters to it, and then passing to the `Context` (at which point I don't think that the underlying `&str` has `'static` anymore) the code still compiles and working without a problem..  Why?

Comment: Just a thought: is this snippet valid, because the temporary `Context` created in the `main`'s scope will only be dropped at the end of the `if let`'s scope because that is taking ownership of the return value of `.parse()`?

Comment: It's no longer `'static`, but it's still a reference to the string defined in `main`, so it's still valid for the duration of `main`. IOW, lifetime `'s` is inferred as "until the end of function `main`".

Comment: @Jmb I think I understand now, posted an answer explaining my understanding of this.  Do you think it is correct now?

Comment: @PeterVaro it’s not “my” style, it’s the Rust community style as agreed upon via RFCs and enacted by rustfmt. I edit every Rust Q&A to provide a uniform experience for people looking for answers to problems without wanting to learn an arbitrary posters white space whims. The point of SO is to quickly read a question to see if it is relevant and the answer to gain information. Non-idiomatic style choices detract from that goal.

Comment: @Shepmaster yeah, except neither the standard library, nor other _official_ code snippets are following the exact same rules as I found out so far, and `rustfmt` (thank god) is configurable and not as stupidly aggressive as `gofmt` or `prettier`..

Answer (score -1):

Thank to the comments of Jmb and some bits of Shepmaster's answer it is indeed clear to me now that my confusion was about the RAII rules and the ownership.

That is, the string was created in the `main` scope, the anonymous `Context` instance is **not** taking ownership of the string it is only borrowing a reference, therefore even when the instance is dropped at the end of `parse_context` along with the borrowed reference, a reference copied to the `Err` object still exists and points to the existing string -- hence we are using the constrained lifetime variables and the compiler is able to reason about the lifetime of the internal string reference.